# Laravel API and Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: angularjs, laravel, satellizer

I am working on a Laravel API, and a angularJS front end application. 
I am trying to make request against my API but I keep having problems with this message in my Google Chrome Console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://larashop.dev/api/authenticate. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Here is a screenshot from my network tab with the response header:
[image]

So, I don't understand because I can see the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*". Here is my `.htaccess` file on my server:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

I really don't know where to look at to solve the problem. What do I miss?

*I also use satellizer with Angular in order to handle authentication*

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key`

Comment: Did you read the error you got carefully?  You are talking about different two headers

Comment: I think this link will help you [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37564989/2085811](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37564989/2085811)