# Laravel cors 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'

Tags: laravel-5, cors, same-origin-policy

I am new to Laravel.

I tried https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors.

When I add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in my public/index.php, it does not add the Content-Type in the response.

When I add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type');
```

It does not add Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I am very confused by all various solutions I find on internet.
How exactly should I go about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a new middleware and add the headers to the response:

Run `php artisan make:middleware ModifyHeadersMiddleware`

Open the file **ModifyHeadersMiddleware** and modify the handle() method:

```
public function handle( $request, Closure $next )
{
    $response = $next( $request );
    $response->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
    $response->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type' );

    return $response;
}
```

Open **app/Http/Kernel.php** and in the `protected $middleware` array add the **ModifyHeadersMiddleware** class.

Comment: It's giving 'Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500'

Comment: I had a mistake in my code, can you copy the **handle** method and try again?

Comment: Nope. It's saying 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' now.

Comment: It did work after updating my php from 5.6 to 7.
Thanks :)