# Laravel 5.6 CORS issue

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport) but it only worked for GET method (as you can see it is mentioned in comments). I also installed [this pakage](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) but again it only works for GET method. This the error I get:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ***my origin*** is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

PHP version: 7.1

Laravel version: 5.6

Frontend application: angular app (Do I need to change sth here?)

```
//Cours.php (middleware I created myself using the first method)
class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT,         
DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}


//cors.php (config/cors.php second method using the laravel-cors package)
return [

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];


//kernel.php
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];


protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
}
```

Comment: Install this package link "https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors" and re-run the project by clear config, route.

Comment: I mentioned the fact that I've already tested this package in the question. But I got the same error.

Comment: Let do one more thing. Instead of adding * to origin add the url of your laravel application. And I expect you clear the cache, route and config of your laravel project

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: I have also set-up the project with same requirement. First time it gives me error but after re-run it works. Anyway could you please update your question with kernel.php and cors.php(config file)

Comment: I added the ones you wanted

Comment: You said you are using "\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class" package then why you need to create cors middleware?

Comment: I tested two different methods. The first method is the one mentioned in another stackoverflow question ( but didn't work). The second method is using the laravel-cors package (didn't work either).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172015/discussion-between-sachin-kumar-and-kasra-gh).

Comment: I have a similar issue with Barryvdh\Cors package.The issue was Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ip/upload. (Reason: expected ‘true’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’).I changed 'supportsCredentials' => true in config/cors.php.I think issue related to 'Orgin' is mentioned in laravel-cors/readme.md as a note. Note: If you are explicitly whitelisting headers, you must include Origin or requests will fail to be recognized as CORS.

Answer (score 2):

No need any type package for laravel-cors.
Just create Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $allowedOrigins = ['http://myroute.xyz', 'http://clarkconcepts.net','http://localhost'];
        $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '';
        if (in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins)) {
            return $next($request)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, cache-control,postman-token, token')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In app/Http/Kernel.php
add Middleware in $middleware section:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, //added here
];
```

Answer (score 1):

you need use first method [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport) without use any package then add also this class to `protected $middleware` like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563350/laravel-cors-access-control-allow-origin-and-access-control-allow-headers) then post method also have desired headers.

it works for me, I hope work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the great laravel-cors package by barryvdh.

After you have the package installed, the easiest way to get CORS support for all your routes is to add the middleware like this in Http/Kernel.php: ($middleware)

```
\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class
```

And edit `config/Cors.php` `'allowedOrigins' => ['*']`

More info check https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I mentioned that I've used this package and I got the same error. Only GET works

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error while trying to create an endpoint for a serial number checker on wordpress using laravel
So just use the cors generated by laravel

````php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;


class CORS {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');

        return $response;
    }
}``` 
Then exclude the route if you are it does not need CSRF protection [as shown here][1] . The cors.php under config remains the same just adjust the `allowed origins`
```php
<?php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Allowed Origins
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Indicate here the origin domains that are allowed to access your API.
    | The '*' wildcard can be used to allow all domains to make requests.
    |
    */

    'allowed_origins' => [
        'http://localhost',
        'http://localhost/wordpresss',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Allowed HTTP Headers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Indicate here the HTTP headers that are allowed when making requests.
    |
    */

    'allowed_headers' =>['*'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Allowed HTTP Methods
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Indicate here the HTTP methods that are allowed when making requests.
    |
    */

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Whether or not the response can be exposed when credentials are present
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Indicates whether or not the response to the request can be exposed when the credentials flag is true.
    | When used as part of a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the actual request
    | can be made using credentials.
    |
    */

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Whether or not the request can include user credentials like cookies, HTTP authentication or client side SSL certificates
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Indicates whether or not the response to the request can be exposed when the credentials flag is true.
    | When used as part of a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the actual request
    | can be made using credentials.
    |
    */

    'allow_credentials' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | The number of seconds the client should cache preflight responses
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Indicates how long the results of a preflight request can be cached in a preflight result cache.
    |
    */

    'max_age' => 0,

];
````

Happy coding glad I could save someone some time!!!